# \crosstabview works in PSQL commandline but doesn't work in PGADMIN

Tags: postgresql, psql, crosstab

Below query works in PSQL but when I execute in PGADMIN it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT sales_stage,geo,count(opp_no) 
FROM bidanalysis group by sales_stage,geo order by 1 
\crosstabview
```

Comment: `\crosstabview` is a `psql` command and doesn't work anywhere else. You will need to use one of the many [SQL alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29) to build a crosstab in pgAdmin

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the option of using crosstab tablefunc but it is not dynamic. I need to define each and every possible column name. Also using crosstabn doesn't work because it doesn't show actual column name but shows it as Category_1 etc

Comment: Tried my luck creating a view from PSQL using above as query. :) of course it did not work as expected. It creates the view successfully but just as the normal listing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\crosstabview is a psql command and doesn't work anywhere else. You will need to use one of the many SQL alternatives to build a crosstab in pgAdmin –   is the right answer but can't flag it as right because it is comment. @a_horse_with_no_name